# Would it take long to brute force a md5 hash like this?

Tags: cryptography, brute-force, md5

- 1be8917510-36.51929856278002
- 10bce1af27-99.18403192423284
- 103fa11cc6-87.21158325206488

Few examples above and as you can see the pattern is:

1xxxxxxxxx-{a percentage (0-100) to 14 decimal places}

x = Any alpha numeric char (abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789)

Am I right in thinking this will take forever even with knowing what some of the values are?

Also which kind of software would allow me to define the inputs like that?

Comment: About 15 hours using 2012 figures. You only have on the order of 10^16 possible inputs, and large scale crackers have been doing in excess of 10^14 per second.

Comment: Hmm not that bad actually, do you know of any software that would let me define my specifications like that when bruting a hash?

Comment: Is every single value equally distributed and statistically independent?